onNewIntent is never called
I am making a launcher app for Android. Inside the main activity, I have overriden the onNewIntent function. When I open an app from my launcher, and then back press, I am sent back to my launcher's home screen. I expect onNewIntent to be called at that exact moment but it is never called. Here is my onNewIntent function :
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    System.out.println("Called");
}

And here is the manifest :
<activity
    android:name="com.example.launcher.MainActivity"
    android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
    android:excludeFromRecents="true"
    android:exported="true"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:stateNotNeeded="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

I do not understand why onNewIntent isn't invoked.
